# Run custom task before ALL possible packaging tasks in gradle android project

Tags: android, gradle

I have a gradle project named `data-android` that applies the `com.android.library` plugin. Before the packaging phase I want a custom task of my own (named `copySqlMigrations`) to be executed. This task copies a bunch of assets into the project tree.

I have made many attempts, but none of them work universally.
The closest I got was adding the following to the end of my gradle file.

```
afterEvaluate {
    assemble.dependsOn copySqlMigrations
    assembleDebug.dependsOn copySqlMigrations
    assembleRelease.dependsOn copySqlMigrations
}
```

This only works if I call e.g. `gradle assembleDebug` directly, but when I want to launch my APK (for which my library project is a dependency), this fails spectacularly.

```
Error:(56, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':data-android'.
      > Could not get unknown property 'assembleDebug' for project ':data-android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

How can I *always* call `:data-android:copySqlMigrations` before this project is being packaged up? I'm looking for a solution that works with all build flavors and all potential invocations (build/run/debug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle has a [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html) accessible via `(project.)tasks`. This container is also a [`TaskCollection`](https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html) containing all tasks. One can query a subset `TaskCollection` via the `matching` method and, thanks to some magic, the new `TaskCollection` is live. So, whenever a new task gets added to the parent `TaskCollection` (or the `TaskContainer`) and it matches the closure of the `matching` method, the subset `TaskCollection` will contain it. Together with the `TaskCollection` `all` method one can handle each task following a pattern whenever it is created.

For the problem stated in your question, I wrote and tested the following build file:

```
task assembleX { }

task copySqlMigrations { }

task assembleY { }

tasks.matching { task ->
    task.name.startsWith('assemble')
}.all { task ->
    task.dependsOn copySqlMigrations
}

task assembleZ { }
```

You can call each `assemble*` task and it will call `copySqlMigrations` as a dependency. Of course, you can modify the matching closure to fit your needs.

Comment: I would like to add that - even though this answer is sublime and accurately responds to my question - I ended up using `preBuild.dependsOn copySqlMigrations`, as this way my custom task is always invoked as part of building my app module, to which my android lib module is a dependency.